# Sass: function as color in rgba

Tags: css, colors, sass, typeerror

I created the map with colors and their modifications (light, dark etc) and custom function for getting values from this map.

```
$colors: (
  text: #383838,
  cyan: (
    base: #54c2e3,
    light: lighten(#54c2e3, 15%),
    dark: darken(#54c2e3, 15%)
  )
)

@function color($color-name, $color-variant:null) {
  @if $color-variant != null {
    @return map-get(map-get($colors,$color-name),$color-variant);
  } @else {
    @if type-of(map-get($colors,$color-name)) == 'map' {
      @return map-get($colors,'base');
    } @else {
      @return map-get($colors,$color-name);
    }
  }
}
```

But when i put this function inside rgba:

```
background: rgba(color(cyan), .5);
```

i get an error

```
Error: argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color
```

**Is there any possible way to use functions as parameters inside sass rgba function?**
Maybe i'm blind, but i couldn't google an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, the problem was with the value returned by the custom function.

The below line of code within the `@if` part of the `@else` condition would actually not return anything based on your settings. You should first get the color's map based on the value passed as argument and then pick the base color value from that map.

```
@return map-get($colors,base);
```

So, the correct `@return` statement should have been like in the below code block.

```
@function color($color-name, $color-variant:null) {
  @if $color-variant != null {
    @return map-get(map-get($colors,$color-name),$color-variant);
  } @else {
    @if type-of(map-get($colors,$color-name)) == 'map' {
      @return map-get(map-get($colors,$color-name),base); /* your problem was here */
    } @else {
      @return map-get($colors,$color-name);
    }
  }
}
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKEozr) (the `a` tag's color and background are set using the output of the function).

Comment: No, this function works as needed, when it's used as is, not as parameter of other function.

Comment: @BogdanDukhevych: But the `@return` in the function - `map-get($colors,'base')` will not fetch any output at all if my understanding of how Sass works is good. You can try the corrected code that I've posted @ http://www.sassmeister.com/ and you'll see that it works.

Comment: @BogdanDukhevych: [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKEozr) is a CodePen Demo. If you click the "View Compiled" button on the CSS box, you'd see the compiled CSS.